# Page refreshes with no reason

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have 2 LinkButtons in my asp.net page. When I click on the first one, I want second one to be visible so I use the following code to achieve it:

LinkButtons:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="LB1" OnClientClick="updateApplet(); return false;" Text="LB1" />

<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="LB2" style="display: none;" Text="LB2" />
```

After some process done in updateApplet() function  I want LB2 to become visible after everyhting is done. However asp page refreshes with no reason.

```
function updateApplet() {

      var msg = document.capture.capture();
      var hiddenControl = '<%= inpHide.ClientID %>';
      document.getElementById(hiddenControl).value = msg;

      document.getElementById('LB2').style.display = 'inherit'; 
      // Without last line everything is perfect but I want LB2 is to be visible and this line refreshes my page :(
      }
```

Can someone help me with my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason for this is that

```
document.getElementById('LB2').style.display
```

crashes your page and the return false of the client click doesn't have chance to run so the page refreshes.

Try

```
document.getElementById('<%= LB2.ClientID %>').style.display = 'inherit'
```

Answer (score 4):

Please check whether your `updateApplet()` function completes normally (that is, there is no JavaScript exception thrown).

By the look of it, your last line causes a JavaScript error and then the `return false;` statement isn't called, and so the default LinkButton's behavior is triggered.

**EDIT:** Yea, I've found it. Your second button's ID isn't `LB2`, you should've done

```
document.getElementById('<%= LB2.ClientID %>').style.display = 'inherit';
```

Answer (score 1):

> return false is missing in your Java Script function.

**Java Script Code**

```
function updateApplet() {

    var msg = document.capture.capture();
    var hiddenControl = '<%= inpHide.ClientID %>';
    document.getElementById(hiddenControl).value = msg;

    document.getElementById('LB2').style.display = 'block'; 
    return false;
}
```

---

**HTML Tag**

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="LB1" OnClientClick="return updateApplet();" 
 Text="LB1" />
```

Comment: this is another way to phrase the same behavior, and it doesn't fix the problem